# Identify the bird

Tags: species-identification, ornithology

Please identify the birds and tell about its details[image: anonymous bird]

Comment: I found this bird in Hyderabad, India

Comment: Why those downvotes?

Answer (score 4):

That is an Australian shell parakeet, or budgerigar. It is a type of seed eating parrot native to Australia. They live a nomadic lifestyle, and inhabit scrublands, open woodlands, and grasslands. They are good mimics -- considered to be one of the top five talking species. Very commonly sold in pet shops. There is an entire Wikipedia page dedicated to it:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Budgerigar

Comment: I found this bird in India not Australia

Comment: The species is distributed across the world as a pet. Sometimes they escape or are purposely set free. If the local climate is suitable, they can survive and even establish local colonies. For example, books on Florida (USA) birds include the budgerigar (e.g. Florida's Birds: A Field Guide and Reference). It would not be surprising to find them in India.

Comment: The bird was stranded at my house and I have rescued it and put it in the cage and the bird keeper said them to be the love birds so I purchased an another male bird of the same kind and kept them together.... And unfortunately the next day morning they both died ...... I didn't know the exact reason of this incident.....can anyone help me out with this...!